# GitKit - How to detect the sign in state of the user on the client side?

Tags: google-identity-toolkit

On my sign in page, I'm using my custom login and logout buttons. In order to show/hide these buttons according to user's sign in state, I need to be able to detect whether user is signed in. I can use the Gitkit's signInSuccess callback and store the user profile information and use that to detect the sign in state, but that approach would fail if the token has expired. I need a more robust approach to detect the sign in state.

The GitKit Sign In button is able to do it correctly. I'm wondering how it does it so that I can follow a similar approach. Can someone shed some light on how the Sign In button detects the sign in state?

Answer (score 1):

You will have to do it on the backend. The status is stored in the gtoken cookie. We provide backend libraries to parse and verify the token. You can get all account info from there too.

Comment: Can I not get the cookie directly from the browser and check its validity (rather than making a trip to the server)? I did a quick test with jquery's cookie plugin and it seems to work correctly. Am I missing something?